# Firebase Quickstart Samples for Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I've decided to try out the Quickstart samples in Firebase for Unity. I haven't changed anything in the codes, and yet I get this error by default in the `UIHandler` script :

> Assets/TestApp/UIHandler.cs(27,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Auth' does not exist in the namespace 'Firebase'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Have I missed something while downloading or am I supposed to add any lines to it? Please Help!

```css
// Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


// Handler for UI buttons on the scene.  Also performs some
// necessary setup (initializing the firebase app, etc) on
// startup.
public class UIHandler : MonoBehaviour {

  Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
  Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user;

  public GUISkin fb_GUISkin;
  private string logText = "";
  private string email = "";
  private string password = "";
  // Enable / disable password input box.
  // NOTE: In some versions of Unity the password input box does not work in
  // iOS simulators.
  public bool usePasswordInput = false;
  private Vector2 controlsScrollViewVector = Vector2.zero;
  private Vector2 scrollViewVector = Vector2.zero;
  bool UIEnabled = true;

  const int kMaxLogSize = 16382;
  Firebase.DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = Firebase.DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;

  // When the app starts, check to make sure that we have
  // the required dependencies to use Firebase, and if not,
  // add them if possible.
  void Start() {
    dependencyStatus = Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckDependencies();
    if (dependencyStatus != Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
      Firebase.FirebaseApp.FixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        dependencyStatus = Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckDependencies();
        if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
          InitializeFirebase();
        } else {
          // This should never happen if we're only using Firebase Analytics.
          // It does not rely on any external dependencies.
          Debug.LogError(
              "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
        }
      });
    } else {
      InitializeFirebase();
    }
  }

  // Handle initialization of the necessary firebase modules:
  void InitializeFirebase() {
    DebugLog("Setting up Firebase Auth");
    auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
  }

  // Exit if escape (or back, on mobile) is pressed.
  void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {
      Application.Quit();
    }
  }

  void OnDestroy() {
    auth.StateChanged -= AuthStateChanged;
    auth = null;
  }

  void DisableUI() {
    UIEnabled = false;
  }

  void EnableUI() {
    UIEnabled = true;
  }

  // Output text to the debug log text field, as well as the console.
  public void DebugLog(string s) {
    Debug.Log(s);
    logText += s + "\n";

    while (logText.Length > kMaxLogSize) {
      int index = logText.IndexOf("\n");
      logText = logText.Substring(index + 1);
    }
    scrollViewVector.y = int.MaxValue;
  }

  // Track state changes of the auth object.
  void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) {
    if (auth.CurrentUser != user) {
      if (user == null && auth.CurrentUser != null) {
        DebugLog("Signed in " + auth.CurrentUser.DisplayName);
      } else if (user != null && auth.CurrentUser == null) {
        DebugLog("Signed out " + user.DisplayName);
      }
      user = auth.CurrentUser;
    }
  }

  public void CreateUser() {
    DebugLog(String.Format("Attempting to create user {0}...", email));
    DisableUI();

    auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password)
      .ContinueWith(HandleCreateResult);
  }

  void HandleCreateResult(Task<Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser> authTask) {
    EnableUI();
    if (authTask.IsCanceled) {
      DebugLog("User Creation canceled.");
    } else if (authTask.IsFaulted) {
      DebugLog("User Creation encountered an error.");
      DebugLog(authTask.Exception.ToString());
    } else if (authTask.IsCompleted) {
      DebugLog("User Creation completed.");
      if (auth.CurrentUser != null) {
        DebugLog("User Info: " + auth.CurrentUser.Email + "   " + auth.CurrentUser.ProviderId);
      }
      DebugLog("Signing out.");
      auth.SignOut();
    }
  }

  public void Signin() {
    DebugLog(String.Format("Attempting to sign in as {0}...", email));
    DisableUI();
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password)
      .ContinueWith(HandleSigninResult);
  }

  // This is functionally equivalent to the Signin() function.  However, it
  // illustrates the use of Credentials, which can be aquired from many
  // different sources of authentication.
  public void SigninWithCredential() {
    DebugLog(String.Format("Attempting to sign in as {0}...", email));
    DisableUI();
    Firebase.Auth.Credential cred = Firebase.Auth.EmailAuthProvider.GetCredential(email, password);
    auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(cred).ContinueWith(HandleSigninResult);
  }

  // Attempt to sign in anonymously.
  public void SigninAnonymously() {
    DebugLog("Attempting to sign anonymously...");
    DisableUI();
    auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(HandleSigninResult);
  }

  void HandleSigninResult(Task<Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser> authTask) {
    EnableUI();
    if (authTask.IsCanceled) {
      DebugLog("SignIn canceled.");
    } else if (authTask.IsFaulted) {
      DebugLog("Login encountered an error.");
      DebugLog(authTask.Exception.ToString());
    } else if (authTask.IsCompleted) {
      DebugLog("Login completed.");
      DebugLog("Signing out.");
      auth.SignOut();
    }
  }

  public void DeleteUser() {
    DebugLog(String.Format("Attempting to delete user {0}...", email));
    DisableUI();
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password)
      .ContinueWith(HandleDeleteSigninResult);
  }

  void HandleDeleteSigninResult(Task<Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser> authTask) {
    EnableUI();
    if (authTask.IsCanceled) {
      DebugLog("Delete signin canceled.");
    } else if (authTask.IsFaulted) {
      DebugLog("Delete signin encountered an error while signing in.");
      DebugLog(authTask.Exception.ToString());
    } else if (authTask.IsCompleted) {
      DisableUI();
      auth.CurrentUser.DeleteAsync().ContinueWith(HandleDeleteResult);
      DebugLog("Signed in - deleting user.");
    }
  }

  void HandleDeleteResult(Task authTask) {
    EnableUI();
    if (authTask.IsCanceled) {
      DebugLog("Delete canceled.");
    } else if (authTask.IsFaulted) {
      DebugLog("Delete encountered an error while signing in.");
      DebugLog(authTask.Exception.ToString());
    } else if (authTask.IsCompleted) {
      DebugLog("Delete completed.");
    }
  }

  // Render the log output in a scroll view.
  void GUIDisplayLog() {
    scrollViewVector = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollViewVector);
    GUILayout.Label(logText);
    GUILayout.EndScrollView();
  }

  // Render the buttons and other controls.
  void GUIDisplayControls(){
    if (UIEnabled) {
      controlsScrollViewVector =
          GUILayout.BeginScrollView(controlsScrollViewVector);
      GUILayout.BeginVertical();
      GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
      GUILayout.Label("Email:", GUILayout.Width(Screen.width * 0.20f));
      email = GUILayout.TextField(email);
      GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

      GUILayout.Space(20);

      GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
      GUILayout.Label("Password:", GUILayout.Width(Screen.width * 0.20f));
      password = usePasswordInput ? GUILayout.PasswordField(password, '*') :
          GUILayout.TextField(password);
      GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

      GUILayout.Space(20);

      if (GUILayout.Button("Create User")) {
        CreateUser();
      }
      if (GUILayout.Button("Sign In Anonymously")) {
        SigninAnonymously();
      }
      if (GUILayout.Button("Sign In With Email")) {
        Signin();
      }
      if (GUILayout.Button("Sign In With Credentials")) {
        SigninWithCredential();
      }
      if (GUILayout.Button("Delete User")) {
        DeleteUser();
      }
      GUILayout.EndVertical();
      GUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }
  }

  // Render the GUI:
  void OnGUI() {
    GUI.skin = fb_GUISkin;
    if (dependencyStatus != Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
      GUILayout.Label("One or more Firebase dependencies are not present.");
      GUILayout.Label("Current dependency status: " + dependencyStatus.ToString());
      return;
    }
    Rect logArea, controlArea;

    if (Screen.width < Screen.height) {
      // Portrait mode
      controlArea = new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, Screen.width, Screen.height * 0.5f);
      logArea = new Rect(0.0f, Screen.height * 0.5f, Screen.width, Screen.height * 0.5f);
    } else {
      // Landscape mode
      controlArea = new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, Screen.width * 0.5f, Screen.height);
      logArea = new Rect(Screen.width * 0.5f, 0.0f, Screen.width * 0.5f, Screen.height);
    }

    GUILayout.BeginArea(logArea);
    GUIDisplayLog();
    GUILayout.EndArea();

    GUILayout.BeginArea(controlArea);
    GUIDisplayControls();
    GUILayout.EndArea();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickstarts don't work by themselves. You must also import the corresponding unitypackage from the Firebase SDK for each one to work. For example, the Auth quickstart requires also importing FirebaseAuth.unitypackage.

Comment: Yes I have done that! I followed through the steps in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: I got the same issues, but even I imported all Firebase Unity libs the issues still there :(